# return back to do more code after sub_delay(2000)

Tags: vb.net, delay

I have a vb.net form+button+textbox + delay sub:

```
'DELAY SUB
 Public Sub Delay(ByVal Milliseconds As Integer)
     Dim Stop_Watch_2 As New Stopwatch
     Stop_Watch_2.Start()
     Do
     Loop Until Stop_Watch_2.ElapsedMilliseconds >= Milliseconds
 End Sub

 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
     For i = 1 To 10
         Delay(2000) ' 2 second delay
         Text_Box1.text = i.ToString
         Button1.Left = Button1.Left + 30
     Next
 End Sub
```

When I run the form, I can see the button is moving to the left every two seconds. The button moving on delay is OK, but the text is not taking the loop value. This delay method for me is better than `thread.Sleep`.

Any suggestions on how to let the text box update its content after the delay interval?

Comment: Thread.Sleep() ?? Maybe

Comment: @Malcor OP was mum on details, but he did say "this delay method for me is better than `thread.Sleep`.

Comment: @TylerH Yeah I caught that after I posted it, its been a long day.

Comment: the `TextBox` is "taking" it, it likely not repainting every update.  Add `Text_Box1.Refresh()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is running synchronously on your UI thread, blocking it from updating the UI until everything is all finished. You'll need to either call [`Text_Box1.Refresh`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or yield control back to the message pump - so the UI can be naturally repainted - with [`Application.DoEvents`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Side note: You're busywaiting and probably shouldn't be. Even if you like this method of delaying better (for timing reasons or otherwise), consider adding a call to `Thread.Sleep` with a small value in your loop to give your user's CPU a break - or at least let it get back to encoding that cat video.

Comment: Thanks a lot, frankly I solved the problem by adding the 'do more code, which is after the timer finish point, I added it inside the timer itself